# I want sharepoint API to list last 5 files that got modified in a range of newer to older

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, file

I want SharePoint API  to list last 5 files that got modified in a range of newer to older.

How to get the top 5 files last modified.

Answer (score 3):

Try using your REST API something like below:

```
siteUrl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Library Name')/items?$select=Title,FileLeafRef&$orderby=Modified desc&$top=5
```

Or if you want to get the files from specific folder then try using below:

```
siteUrl/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Site Name/Library Name/Folder Name')/Files?$select=FileLeafRef,ListItemAllFields&$expand=ListItemAllFields&$orderby=ListItemAllFields/Modified desc&$top=5
```

**official documentation**: [Working with folders and files with REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest).

Comment: Thanks a ton Ganesh. It worked.
I used the following:

Comment: Thanks a ton Ganesh. It worked.
I used the following:
"https://ericsson.sharepoint.com/sites/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared%20Documents/Project%20Logs/T-Mobile/1052/TMO%20Integration%20Migration/AZ')/files?$orderby=ListItemAllFields/Modified%20desc&$top=5"


Thank you again
Best Regards